# How to assign value of such code to variable?

Tags: php

I have file db.php from Yii 2 with such code:

```
<?php

return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => '',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

I plan to include this file in my code.

How to assign returned value to my variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this file being called *db.php*, just do something like

```
$config = require './path/to/db.php';
```